# How to keep android application running in sleep mode?

Tags: android

The problem is that my app stops working in sleep mode. The user wants to take orders in sleep mode via a bluetooth scanner. Is there any class which keeps the phone in sleep mode and in the background it takes orders, or any suggestion to achieve that task or any example app?

Comment: I'd like an answer to this too...

Answer (score 7):

Its not recommended to run your application in sleep mode, unless you really need that. That's because this drastically affects batter life.

In your case you need to acquire `WakeLock`. You can create new `WakeLock` instance using [`PowerManager.newWakeLock()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).

---

An example from documentation:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(
                                          Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                                      PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
                                      | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                                      TAG);
wl.acquire();
// ...
wl.release()
```

This should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I had tried  Partial_wake _lock because  i need  screen off not dim but  partial_wake _lock is not working why?